# No funciona OPEN al tratar de abrir un cursor

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor

Soy nuevo con SQL y estoy intentando abrir un cursor en Postgres, pero al ejecutarlo me falla en el "open", lo que me resulta re extraño.

```
DECLARE aa CURSOR FOR SELECT expiration_time, category, event_id FROM user_alert;
OPEN aa;
```

Esto da el error ->

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "OPEN"
LINE 3:  OPEN aa;
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 97
```

estuve googleando un buen rato y al parecer esta es la sintaxis para abrir un cursor. Algunos varían encerrando el OPEN entre un begin/end, pero de todas formas sigue fallando en el "open".

Mi version de psql es 10.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PostgreSQL los cursores se deben usar dentro de un bloque de transacción `BEGIN/END`, si lo vas a usar fuera de una función no es necesario explicitar en `OPEN`, pues el `DECLARE...` lo hace por ti, pero si lo haces dentro de una función si es necesario el `OPEN`.

Fuera de una función:

```
begin ;

    DECLARE aa CURSOR FOR SELECT expiration_time, category, event_id FROM user_alert;
    fetch all from  aa ;

end;
```

Dentro de una funcion:

```
create or replace function c() returns void as $$
declare 
    DECLARE aa CURSOR FOR SELECT expiration_time, category, event_id FROM user_alert;

begin 
  open aa;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;

begin ;
 select c();
 fetch all from  aa ;

end;
```

Comment: Perfecto Anthony, es exactamente eso que comentaste! Muchas gracias